How do I override auto formats in {tern} functions?
Considering {tern} and {rtables} package formatting functions, can you override auto formats in {tern} functions like count_patients_with_flags?
For example:
library(rtables)
library(tern)
library(dplyr)

# Add labelled flag variables to analysis dataset.
adae <- tern_ex_adae %>%
  mutate(
    fl1 = TRUE %>% with_label("Total AEs"),
    fl2 = (TRTEMFL == "Y") %>%
      with_label("Total number of patients with at least one adverse event"),
    fl3 = (TRTEMFL == "Y" & AEOUT == "FATAL") %>%
      with_label("Total number of patients with fatal AEs"),
    fl4 = (TRTEMFL == "Y" & AEOUT == "FATAL" & AEREL == "Y") %>%
      with_label("Total number of patients with related fatal AEs")
  )

lyt_adae <- basic_table(show_colcounts = TRUE) %>%
  split_cols_by("ACTARM") %>%
  analyze_num_patients(
    vars = "USUBJID",
    .stats = c("unique", "nonunique"),
    .labels = c(
      unique = "Total number of patients with at least one AE",
      nonunique = "Total number of AEs"
    ),
    .formats = list(unique = format_count_fraction_fixed_dp, nonunique = "xx"),
    show_labels = "hidden"
  ) %>%
  count_patients_with_flags(
    "USUBJID",
    flag_variables = c("fl1", "fl2", "fl3", "fl4"),
    denom = "N_col",
    var_labels = "Total number of patients with at least one",
    show_labels = "visible"
  )

result_adae <- build_table(lyt_adae, df = adae)

I'm trying to change a variable count & percentage to a fraction & percentage. So from 10 (50%) to 10/20 (50%).
As the analyze_num_patients function above, I could override the default function in the count_patients_with_flags function by adding in the last function the .formats as follows:
 count_patients_with_flags(
     "USUBJID",
     flag_variables = aesi_vars,
     denom = "N_col",
     var_labels = "Total number of patients with at least one",
     show_labels = "visible",
    .formats = c(count_fraction = format_count_fraction))
   )                     

However, the function does not seem to use' format_count_fraction', and the result is identical.

You can override the formats with a custom format function. Note that you need to retrieve again the total counts from the fraction.
library(tern)
library(dplyr)

# Add labelled flag variables to analysis dataset.
adae <- tern_ex_adae %>%
  mutate(
    fl1 = TRUE %>% with_label("Total AEs"),
    fl2 = (TRTEMFL == "Y") %>%
      with_label("Total number of patients with at least one adverse event"),
    fl3 = (TRTEMFL == "Y" & AEOUT == "FATAL") %>%
      with_label("Total number of patients with fatal AEs"),
    fl4 = (TRTEMFL == "Y" & AEOUT == "FATAL" & AEREL == "Y") %>%
      with_label("Total number of patients with related fatal AEs")
  )
my_format_func <- function(x, ...) {
  attr(x, "label") <- NULL
  
  if (any(is.na(x))) {
    return("NA")
  }
  # browser()
  checkmate::assert_vector(x)
  checkmate::assert_int(x[1])
  checkmate::assert_number(x[2], lower = 0, upper = 1) # the stat returns a fraction
  
  result <- if (x[1] == 0) {
    paste0(x[1])
  } else {
    dn <- round(x[1] / x[2]) # Retrieving the denominator
    paste0(
      x[1], "/", dn,
      " (", round(x[2] * 100, 1), "%)"
    )
  }
  
  return(result)
}
lyt_adae <- basic_table(show_colcounts = TRUE) %>%
  split_cols_by("ACTARM") %>%
  analyze_num_patients(
    vars = "USUBJID",
    .stats = c("unique", "nonunique"),
    .labels = c(
      unique = "Total number of patients with at least one AE",
      nonunique = "Total number of AEs"
    ),
    .formats = list(unique = format_count_fraction_fixed_dp, nonunique = "xx"),
    show_labels = "hidden"
  ) %>%
  count_patients_with_flags(
    "USUBJID",
    flag_variables = c("fl1", "fl2", "fl3", "fl4"),
    denom = "N_col",
    var_labels = "Total number of patients with at least one",
    show_labels = "visible",
    .formats = c(count_fraction = my_format_func)
  )

result_adae <- build_table(lyt_adae, df = adae)
result_adae
#>                                                                A: Drug X        B: Placebo     C: Combination
#>                                                                 (N=202)          (N=177)          (N=162)    
#> —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
#> Total number of patients with at least one AE                  59 (29.2%)       57 (32.2%)       48 (29.6%)  
#> Total number of AEs                                               202              177              162      
#> Total number of patients with at least one                                                                   
#>   Total AEs                                                  59/202 (29.2%)   57/177 (32.2%)   48/162 (29.6%)
#>   Total number of patients with at least one adverse event   59/202 (29.2%)   57/177 (32.2%)   48/162 (29.6%)
#>   Total number of patients with fatal AEs                    28/202 (13.9%)   31/177 (17.5%)   20/162 (12.3%)
#>   Total number of patients with related fatal AEs            28/202 (13.9%)   31/177 (17.5%)   20/162 (12.3%)

Created on 2024-07-03 with reprex v2.1.0

Hey @Garini thank you so so much for all your help! This  helped me so much. I used the wrong argument checks when I tried rewriting the function & overcomplicated the overwrite. I appreciate all your help!
